# spritebuilder/cocos2d music toggle

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, spritebuilder

I have the following method:

```
-(void)musicToggle
{
// if the audio is off, turn it on, if it's on turn it off
if (!_audioIsOn)
{
    [music setTitle:@"on"];
    [[OALSimpleAudio sharedInstance] playBg:@"carefree.mp3" loop:YES];
    _audioIsOn = TRUE;
}
else
{
    [music setTitle:@"off"];
    OALSimpleAudio *audio = [OALSimpleAudio sharedInstance];
    [audio stopBg];
    _audioIsOn = FALSE;

}
}
```

When the app starts, music is off. Pressing the button turns music off and on, BUT even though the music plays during all my scenes, I don't know how to get the state of the music in order for the label and method to by in sync.

If I press the button in any other scene OR if I return to the original scene, the music starts from the beginning.

Can someone please help me with a bit of code?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE
Through a little more searching I modified the method as follows (the music bit works as needed, BUT the label won't update. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.):

```
-(void)musicToggle
{
// if the audio is off, turn it on, if it's on turn it off
BOOL shouldMuteSound = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"shouldMuteSound"];
shouldMuteSound = !shouldMuteSound;
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:shouldMuteSound forKey:@"shouldMuteSound"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
//if (!_audioIsOn)
if(shouldMuteSound)
{
    [[OALSimpleAudio sharedInstance] playBg:@"carefree.mp3" loop:YES];
    _audioIsOn = TRUE;
    [music setTitle:@"on"];
}
else
{
    OALSimpleAudio *audio = [OALSimpleAudio sharedInstance];
    [audio stopBg];
    _audioIsOn = FALSE;
    [music setTitle:@"off"];
}
}
```

Comment: save the audio on off state with nsuserdefaults

Comment: can you help me with some code please? i tried implementing it once but it didn't work out. thanks.